# How to restore pg_dump file into mysql database?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a backup file which I obtained using `pg_dump` command in linux mint. I want to restore this database file into a `mysql` database. I am using `dbeaver` tool. The command I used to get the database backup was this.

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f "/home/james/BACKUPFILE.bak" DB_NAME
```

I am able to restore this backupfile into another postgres database fine but I need to restore the same into a mysql database.

Command I am using to restore the backup into postgres database is

```
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d DB_NAME_NEW -v "/home/james/BACKUPFILE.bak"
```

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply `pg_dump` from a Postgres database and expect to be able to load it into a MySQL database, since there are syntactical differences between the two database engines, along with some differences in structure/organization (e.g., storage engines).  In order to perform this task, you'll need to use a third-party migration tool (seems that [pg2mysql](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/pg2mysql) is a pretty well-known one).

Otherwise, you can try using [DBeaver's `Export Data` function](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Data-migration) and see if you can map columns/tables (or create tables) as desired.

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://www.enterprisedb.com)